# Generate Random String of 3000 bytes

Tags: java, string, random

I am working on a project in which people have asked me to `generate random String of 3000 bytes`.

Is it possible to do? I am confuse how we can generate random string of 3000 bytes?

I know of something like this-

```
SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
String rand = new BigInteger(176, srandom).toString(32);
```

But it will not be `3000 bytes`

Is there any way I can get random string of `3000 bytes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SecureRandom's `nextBytes()` method:

```
final SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
final byte []data = new byte[3000];
srandom.nextBytes(data);
```

If you need the random string to contain printable characters then you can do the following:

```
public enum StringUtils
{
  INSTANCE;

  private static final String CANDIDATES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  private static final int CANDIDATESLEN;

  static
  {
    CANDIDATESLEN = CANDIDATES.length();
  }

  public static String generateRandomString(int length)
  {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      sb.append(CANDIDATES.charAt(RANDOMSOURCE.nextInt(CANDIDATESLEN)));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

You can change the CANDIDATES string to whatever you need.  Be aware that 3000 characters does not necessarily imply 3000 bytes as this is down to your candidate selection and character encoding, but if you stick with the above candidates and UTF-8 encoding you should be fine.

Comment: Updated answer with example.  One thing that you didn't mention is if you need the results to be any bytes or if they need to result in a printable string.  Answer will be a bit different if the latter.

Comment: I need to be in a printable string. What changes then I will be making then?